# Show an attachment image inside a Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need some help on lightning components. I'm trying to show attachment image using lightning components but the image is not shown.

```
<aura:component controller="AttachmentClass">
<aura:attribute name="myObjects" type="Attachment[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="attchid" type="String" default="00P900000115nZx"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getOpps}"/>
      <aura:attribute name="prefixURL" type="String" default="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/"/>

   <h2>All Record</h2>
       <table border="2px" ><tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.myObjects}" var="SelectOperation">
          <tr>
            <th>ParentId</th>
              <th>BodyLength</th>
                 <th>Image</th>
            </tr>
    .   <tr>   
            <td><option text="{!SelectOperation.ParentId}"/></td>
       <td><option text="{!SelectOperation.BodyLength}"/></td>

       <td><img class="mythumbnail" src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+SelectOperation.attchid}" width="100" height="100"/></td>
             <td><img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + v.attchid}" alt=""/></td>
       </tr>
       </aura:iteration>
       </tbody></table>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `aura:iteration` loop through your `myObjects` variable which is an array of `Attachment` objects.

Then, each `SelectOperation` variable is an `Attachment` object. So the `attchid` property doesn't exist. If you want to display the attachment you have to use the `Id` property like this:

```
<img class="mythumbnail" src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+SelectOperation.Id}" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Comment: Thankyou sir for your ans. but in this cod i can only see image i can not see the  pdf file

Comment: @LokeshMalviya You cannot show a pdf deom an HTML IMG tag. Instead you should use a either a javascript pdf viewer like the [PDF.JS](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/), or maybe you can render the pdf as it own page inside an iframe: `<iframe src={!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+SelectOperation.Id} />'`

Comment: tq for your again ans. sir but i have allready used it and using this cod we can not see image in responsive way

Comment: please sir i need your help